# Excel VBA - Split array and return as list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of cell addresses saved as a range, which I then want to return as a list of individual cell addresses. I can't seem to find anything online that says this is posible, does anyone know otherwise?

Many thanks

What I have got so far:

Function AN()

Dim CellRange As String
Dim a() As String
Dim intCount As Integer

Dim strTemp

```
For Each C In ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Range("A1:A46")
    If C = "" Then
        C.Select
        CellRange = Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)).Address
        a = split(CellRange)
            For intCount = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
            MsgBox a(intCount)

            Next
```

This gives me the two extremes of the range, but not the cells in between. Split doesn't seem to be working - I'm still getting to grips with it so please forgive any errors there .. it's been a long day!

Comment: Actually I think you can take each cell in the range and add then to a list ... what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to convert a range into a string of addresses, comma-separated:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, s As String
    Set r = Range("A1,B9,D13,J78,l987")
    s = r.Address(0, 0)
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

You can make this into an *array* of strings using **Split():**

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, s As String
    Set r = Range("A1,B9,D13,J78,l987")
    s = r.Address(0, 0)
    MsgBox s
    ary = Split(s, ",")
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 This is good. I would also add an easy to access link to [Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) though.

Comment: @Sifu ______________Thanks! _____________I have amended the post.

Comment: Thanks for this - Actually the issue is that I am trying to return the values for all cells in a range that is not defined like this, but instead like:

Range("A1:A20")

Which I would then like to have the cells listed as A1, A2, A3 and so on. Can this be done?